# Specifying Shared Drive Scope for Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google Shared Drive with the company I work for (note that this is different than shared folders that come up in Shared With Me - no one person owns the Shared Drive, a team owns/manages it).

I'd like to have script that exists within the Shared Drive and has access to the Shared Drive (ie the scope is within the Shared Drive). DriveApp, by default, has the scope of the creator's My Drive as far as I understand. So I can create a script saved within the Shared Drive but DriveApp is still only within the scope of My Drive.

This code

```
var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
console.log("Root Folder:", rootFolder.getName());
```

always returns `Root Folder: My Drive`

Is there a way to specify which Drive the DriveApp runs as? I.e. get the above code to return `Root Folder: Shared Drive Name`

Answer (score 1):

In the current stage, unfortunately, `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` returns the root folder of own Google Drive. So in order to retrieve the root folder of the shared Drive, I would like to propose the following script.

#### Sample script:

If the shared Drive is only one, how about the following sample script? When you use this, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). In this script, the drive ID and name of the shared Drive are retrieved using the method of "Drives: list" in Drive API.

```
var drive = Drive.Drives.list().items[0];
var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(drive.id);
console.log("Root Folder:", drive.name);

// When you want to retrieve the files, you can also use the following script.
var files = rootFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  console.log(files.next().getName())
}
```

#### Note:

- From June 1, 2020, Drive service like `DriveApp` got to be able to use the shared Drive. But in the current stage, it seems that all functions cannot be used for the shared Drive. I believe that these might be able to be resolved in the future update.
- For example, in the current stage, when above script is used, unfortunately, `rootFolder.getName()` is not the name of shared Drive. In my environment, it's `Drive`. So I used `drive.name`.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/drives/list)